# When to create crosstalk.SelectionHandle

Tags: javascript, r, htmlwidgets

The authoring page https://rstudio.github.io/crosstalk/authoring.html says to create `sel_handle` at factory scope, before returning `renderValue` and `resize`.  Is this necessary (e.g. because it needs to be created before `renderValue` is called), or could it be created in  `renderValue()`, and attached to `scatter`?  I'm referring to the sample code from that page, i.e.

```
HTMLWidgets.widget({

  name: 'd3scatter',

  type: 'output',

  factory: function(el, width, height) {

    var firstRun = true;
    var scatter = d3scatter(el).width(width).height(height);

    var sel_handle = new crosstalk.SelectionHandle();

    scatter.on("brush", function(keys) {
      sel_handle.set(keys);
    });

    sel_handle.on("change", function(e) {
      if (e.sender !== sel_handle) {
        scatter.clearBrush();
      }
      scatter.selection(e.value);
    });

    return {
      renderValue: function(x) {
        var value = x.data;
        scatter
          .x_var(value.x_var)
          .y_var(value.y_var)
          .color_var(value.color_var)
          .color_spec(value.color_spec)
          .x_label(value.x_label)
          .y_label(value.y_label)
          .x_lim(value.x_lim)
          .y_lim(value.y_lim)
          .key(x.settings.crosstalk_key);

        sel_handle.setGroup(x.settings.crosstalk_group);

        scatter(!firstRun);
        firstRun = false;
      },
      resize: function(width, height) {
        scatter.width(width).height(height)(false);
      }
    };
  }
});
```

I'm considering putting the creating into `renderValue()` because in many cases my widget won't use `sharedData`, so I don't want to unnecessarily link in the `crosstalkLibs`.  But I won't know this until I see `x` for the first time in `renderValue`.

The sample code might end up something like this:

```
HTMLWidgets.widget({

  name: 'd3scatter',

  type: 'output',

  factory: function(el, width, height) {

    var firstRun = true;
    var scatter = d3scatter(el).width(width).height(height);

    return {
      renderValue: function(x) {
        var value = x.data;
        scatter
          .x_var(value.x_var)
          .y_var(value.y_var)
          .color_var(value.color_var)
          .color_spec(value.color_spec)
          .x_label(value.x_label)
          .y_label(value.y_label)
          .x_lim(value.x_lim)
          .y_lim(value.y_lim)
          .key(x.settings.crosstalk_key);

        if (firstRun && typeof x.settings !== "undefined") {
          scatter.sel_handle = new crosstalk.SelectionHandle();

          scatter.on("brush", function(keys) {
            scatter.sel_handle.set(keys);
          });

          scatter.sel_handle.on("change", function(e) {
            if (e.sender !== sel_handle) {
              scatter.clearBrush();
            }
            scatter.selection(e.value);
          });

          scatter.sel_handle.setGroup(x.settings.crosstalk_group);
        }
        scatter(!firstRun);
        firstRun = false;
      },
      resize: function(width, height) {
        scatter.width(width).height(height)(false);
      }
    };
  }
});
```

This is untested code so it may contain typos, but will this general approach cause problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of days of experimentation:  the answer to my question is that the sample approach works, but is not necessary.  There is at least one error in the proposed modification to the code:  the test for whether the change message came from the same component should be

```
if (e.sender !== this) {
  scatter.clearBrush();
}
```

but in general the approach is fine.